# copy rows to new sheet by checking key array in GAS

Tags: java, google-apps-script, key

I'm trying to copy rows from one sheet to another by checking a key column 'O'.

```
function keyPush(){
  var thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('##');
  var origSheet = thisSheet.getSheetByName('original');
  var origLastRow = origSheet.getLastRow();
  var newSheet= thisSheet.getSheetByName('copy');
  var tkhLastRow = newSheet.getLastRow();
  var keyCol = 'O';
  var key = origSheet.getRange(keyCol+'2:'+keyCol+origLastRow).getValues();
  for(var row=key.length-1;row>1;row--){
    if( origSheet.getRange('O'+row) != 'done' )
    {
      var orig = origSheet.getRange('A'+row+':N'+row);
      var dest = newSheet.getRange('C'+tkhLastRow+':P'+tkhLastRow);
      orig.copyTo(dest,{contentOnly:true});
      origSheet.getRange('O'+row).setValue('done');
    }
  }
}
```

I'm missing a loop or something because I can see the rows being iterated through on the new sheet. I need it to only copy the rows not marked done to the new sheet. Right now its pushing all rows from the origSheet into the same row of the newSheet which is why I can see it happen.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the working code if it's helpful to anyone.

```
function pushRow(){
  var thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('##');
  var origSheet = thisSheet.getSheetByName('original');
  var origLastRow = origSheet.getLastRow();
  var tkhContacts = thisSheet.getSheetByName('contacts');
  var keyCol = 'O';
  var keys = origSheet.getRange(keyCol+'2:'+keyCol+origLastRow);
  var keyRow = keys.getRow();
    for(var row=origLastRow;row>1;row--){
      if( origSheet.getRange(keyCol+row).getValue().trim() != 'done' )
      {
        var orig = origSheet.getRange('A'+row+':N'+row).getValues();
        tkhContacts.appendRow(
          [ '','',orig[0][0],orig[0][1],orig[0][2],orig[0][3],orig[0][4],orig[0][5],orig[0][6],orig[0][7],orig[0][8],orig[0][9],orig[0][10],orig[0][11],orig[0][12],orig[0][13],'','','' ] )
        origSheet.getRange(keyCol+row).setValue('done');
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to get the new value from newSheet last row, so it will put it on the same row each time. Here is a correction

```
function keyPush(){
  var thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('##');
  var origSheet = thisSheet.getSheetByName('original');
  var origLastRow = origSheet.getLastRow();
  var newSheet= thisSheet.getSheetByName('copy');
  var tkhLastRow = newSheet.getLastRow();
  var keyCol = 'O';
  var key = origSheet.getRange(keyCol+'2:'+keyCol+origLastRow).getValues();
  for(var row=key.length-1;row>1;row--){
    if( origSheet.getRange('O'+row) != 'done' )
    {
      tkhLastRow = newSheet.getLastRow();
      var orig = origSheet.getRange('A'+row+':N'+row);
      var dest = newSheet.getRange('C'+tkhLastRow+':P'+tkhLastRow);
      orig.copyTo(dest,{contentOnly:true});
      origSheet.getRange('O'+row).setValue('done');
    }
  }
}
```

Also, you should consider using [apprendRow(content) method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) which is atomical and avoid such problem as get the new value of last row each time you write some data.

Comment: I've got `tkhLastRow = newSheet.getLastRow();` declared higher up. Does redeclaring it in the IF statement do something else?

Comment: It's not about declaring. The tkhLastRow value will not change if you just get it at start of your program. For exemple, the last row is row 3: You will have `tkhLastRow = 3`. the first line you'll copy will be on row 3 so. But after that, if you don't update your tkhLastRow value, it will stay at 3 instead of 4. So it will always right on the same row, which seems to be your problem.